# Looking for secure rules to access all existing usernames

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am looking for a secure way to check whether a username is unique before creating a new account in the Firebase.

Since I use the function CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync() in Unity, the Firebase build in mechanism checks whether the e-mail address is unique.

Hence, I have to read all existing usernames before creating the new user.
My idea so far is to additionally store all usernames (and nothing more) in a separate area "usernames" which has the following simple access rule, which allow every user (also the new ones without authentication) to access this data.
The actual user data is stored underneath users, where I restricted the access to the actual owner.

Since this is my first time I try to set up a secure and meaningful way for a potential productive app, I would be grateful to get feedback to my intended approach.

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "usernames": {
      // can be accessed without authentication, so before the new user is created. 
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true      
    },
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account // whose uid must exactly match the key ($userId)
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic approach sounds reasonable to me, although I'd make a few additions to the rules:

- No user should be able to write `/usernames`, as that'd mean anyone can wipe all users with a single write. Instead you probably want them to be able to write each individual username, so with a write rule on `/usernames/$username`.
- You actually don't need to be able to read all usernames, to check if a specific username exists. So this rule too, you can move to `/usernames/$username`.
- I assume that a user can only claim a username once they're signed in, so you'll want to add a `auth !== null` check there.
- I recommend storing the UID of the user who claimed the specific name as the value of that `/usernames/$username` node, so you'll want to enforce that in the security rules too.
- With that you can then ensure that a user can only delete the username they claimed, and nobody else's.

There probably some more things you could do, but the above steps would definitely be major steps forward already.